# How to run texmath which is installed via cabal?

Tags: linux, installation, cabal, pandoc

I had installed texmath and pandoc through cabal. If I run pandoc through command line(/home/.cabal/bin/pandoc), it works. But when I try to run (/home/.cabal/bin/texmath) it outputs as command not found.

Texmath is installed but don't know how to run this package.[image: Texmath(Installed)]

when I run `cabal install -fexecutable --reinstall texmath` am getting this output.

[image: output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [texmath documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/texmath)

> By default, only the Haskell library is installed. To install a test
>   program, texmath, use the executable Cabal flag:
>
> cabal install -fexecutable

This should thus solve your problem:

```
cabal install -fexecutable --force-reinstalls texmath
```